# What is the best way to invoke Nmap in C/C++?

Tags: c++, nmap

I am developing protocol fuzzing software in C/C++. I need a way to monitor the status of the fuzzing target (like ports, services). Is Nmap a good choice? If yes, then how to invoke Nmap in C/C++, is there an API? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you really need, you did not provide any additional information in your question. In my opinion you can follow two different ways:

1. use nmap *outside* your program, as an external tool
2. use [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) *inside* your software to analyze network traffic and obtain the information you need

Comment: libpcap is too low level, a lot of work need to be done. It seems that nmap doesn't provide an API to invoke its DLLs. The external way (CMD) is a little less-efficient.